# Counting arrangements around a table with constraints

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

I have $n$ guests seated around a circular table. I want to serve them meals so that given any two guests $u$ and $v$, either

i. $u$ and $v$ have different meals, or

ii. $u$'s two neighbors have a different set of meals than $v$'s two neighbors.

How many different meals do I need?

Thoughts:
If I have $m$ meals, there are $m$ ways to pick a guest's meal and $(m+1)(m)/2$ ways to pick his neighbors' meals. So, it must be that $(m+1)(m)^2/2 ≥ n$.

For example, at $m=3$, $(m+1)(m)^2/2 = 18$ And, I believe for $n=18$, $m=3$ is sufficient with the following assignment of meals $\{1,2,3\}$ going around the table: 122231333232111312.

However, at $m=4$, $(m+1)(m)^2/2 = 40$, and I don't believe that $m=4$ is sufficient when $n=40$. (I reasoned this by looking at Euler circuits on De Bruijn graphs with some edges deleted. I won't go into the details as I suspect there is a much easier approach to this problem.)

Thank you.

Comment: Just a comment: I think $2n^{1/3}$ is sufficient because if you randomly serve your guests, the chances that you will have two guests seeing the same configuration is less than 1. So the upper and lower bounds differ only by multiplicative factors.